# Encoding issues over SSH characters shown as ~@~X in vim

Tags: ssh, terminal, vim, encoding

I am having issues when viewing a file through `SSH`
I have 2 computers connected to each other `myServer` 'myHost' , sharing over 'SSH' a session.

On `myServer` I have got a log from `wget` which originates an issue when viewing the file either on `vim` or on `nano` with different effects

If the file is viewed localy (no SSH)

```
Saving to: '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/vim-dan-original/manpagesdeb1/downloaded/debian-bookworm/1+.html'
```

Whereas if I view the same file over ssh I get
In nano

```
Saving to:  ^`^x/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/vim-dan-original/manpagesdeb1/downloaded/debian-bookworm/1+.html ^`^y
```

In vim

```
Saving to: ~@~X/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/vim-dan-original/manpagesdeb1/downloaded/ddebian-bookworm/1+.html~@~Y
```

Comment: Where does `^\`^x` come from?

Comment: No idea , it is the output of `wget -o  mylog` That is what I get when I open it using `nano` rather than `vim`

Comment: These are probably binary characters. I guess that the `^` means Ctrl, so that `^x` means Ctrl-X. I wonder if these are control characters that you type yourself and that get added to the file-name.

Comment: "If the file is viewed locally" - How? How do you view it? Nano, Vim, anything else?

Comment: What is the actual contents of the file? Please show us the output of `hexdump -C filename`.

Comment: I've run `wget -o mylog http://something`. In the log file's "Saving to:" line there are fancy Unicode quotes U+2018 `‘` and U+2019 `’` rather than the plain ASCII `'`. You should make sure that all your systems are properly configured for UTF-8 and the command `locale charmap` reports `UTF-8` without any warning.

Comment: Thanks egmont. So It is a problem of the way wget generates its logfile. I guess it shouldnt be doing this

Comment: @freddie_ventura Why not? What's the problem with using UTF-8 characters? It should be perfectly fine. The problem is with anyone not being able to display them properly. Most Linux distributions switched to using UTF-8 by default about 15-20 years ago. Whatever systems you're using, they should be able to handle it fine, by default, out of the box. You should find and fix the component that breaks it. If your `wget` does the same as mine then the culprit is not that.